# Cluster design for downloading/streaming a dataset to a user

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

In our system, we classically have two components: A Cloudera Hadoop cluster (CDH) and an OpenShift "backend" system. In HDFS, we have some huge .parquet files.

We now have a business requirement to "export the data by a user given filter criterion" to a user in "realtime" as downloadable file. So the flow is: The user enters a SQL like filter string, for instance `user='Theo' and command='execution'`. He then sends a GET `/export` request to our backend service with the filter string as parameter. The user shall now get a "download file" from his web browser and immediately start downloading that file as CSV (even if its multiple terrabytes or even petabytes in size, thats the user's choice if he wants to try out and wait that long). In fact, the cluster should respond *synchronously* but not cache the entire response on a single node before sending the result but only receive data at "internet speed" of the user and directly stream it to the user. (With a buffer of e.g. 10 oder 100 MB).

I now face the problem on how to best approach this requirement. My considerations:

I wanted to use Spark for that. Spark would read the Parquet file, apply the filter easily and then "coalesce" the filtered result to the driver which in turn streams the data back to the requesting backend/client. During this task, the driver should of course not run out of memory if the data is sent too slowly back to the backend/user, but just have the executors deliver the data in the same speed as it is "consumed").

However, I face some problems here:

1. The standard use case is that the user has fine grained filters so that his exported file contains something like 1000 lines only. If I'd submit a new spark job via `spark-submit` for each request, I already come into latencies of multiple seconds due to initialization and query plan creation (Even if its just as simple as reading and filtering the data). I'd like to avoid that.
2. The cluster and the backend are strictly isolated. The operation guys ideally don't want us to reach the cluster from the backend at all, but the cluster should just call the backend. We are able to "open" maybe one port, but we'll possibly not able to argue something like "our backend will run the spark driver but being connected to the cluster as execution backend".
3. Is it a "bad design smell" if we run a "server spark job", i.e. we submit an application with mode "client" to the cluster master which also opens a port for HTTP requests and only runs a spark pipeline on requests, but holds the spark context open all the time (and is reachable from our backend via a fixed URL)? I know that there is "spark-job-server" project which does this, but it still feels a bit weird due to the nature of Spark and Jobs, where "naturally" a job would be to download a file and not be a 24h running server waiting to execute some pipeline steps from time to time.
4. I have no idea on how to limit sparks result fetching so that the executors send in a speed so that the driver won't run out of memory if the user requested petabytes.. Any suggestion on this?

Is Spark a good choice for this task after all or do you have any suggestions for better tooling here? (At best in CDH 5.14 environment as we don't get the operation team to install any additional tool).

Comment: Not sure I understand why you need a REST API for this. You are basically making standard SQL calls which can be done to Spark/Hive ThriftServer or over JDBC/ODBC... If you want CSV exports, I think something like Dremio , Superset, or Hue can give that